# jquery if statement issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to check the if the filename variable is empty. I use

```
$.each(rows, function(rowIndex, row){





        var fileName = $.trim(fields[0]).toLowerCase();

                //will output fileName 
        console.log(fileName );             

        //out -1,5,3,15,15,5,5,6,7,-1,3,5,5
                console.log(fileName.indexOf('.html'));     

        if(fileName.indexOf('.html') < 0 || window.location.href.toLowerCase().indexOf(fileName) < 0) //invalid or different file, skip this row
        {
            //if the filename is empty skip this loop and check next loop filename variable

            return true;
        }

        //the above script is to check to see if the filename is empty.         

                var $element = $('#' + fileName );

                //doesn't show anything at all.
                console.log(fileName );    

})
```

everything before my 'if' statement will show but not after it.

Thanks for the helps.

Comment: instead of `return true;`, just use `return;`.

Comment: Put a `console.log()` _inside_ the if statement - if the if condition is true the function stops at that point as per the comment in the code. What is the purpose of the `$.each()` in this case? You're not using `rowIndex` or `row` anywhere in your callback. What is in `rows`? Where is `fields` defined?

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement has "return true" in it. This returns/finishes your main function.

Change:

before if add:

```
var is_valid = false;
```

and in if:

```
is_valid = true;
```

This way it will not prematurely exit. 'var' in there is to make this variable local to scope of your function and it doesn't leak memory.

Comment: _We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false. Returning non-false is the same as a continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next iteration._ [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)